# Reading an array from a file then writing it to another

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, data-structures

I believe I have a problem with my structure pointer (head), but I'm not sure where I'm doing wrong. It reads the data from the file fine for the `headercheck` function so I have no clue if that's it or not. I would rather have the structure pointer global, because this is part of a very big program with switch case statements and all that, but it doesn't like that.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

#include <string.h>

#define maxheight 1080
#define maxwidth 1920
#define RGB_COMPONENT_COLOUR 255
#define pgmtype "P2"
#define ppmtype "P3"

typedef struct {
    int x, y;
}
PPMImage;

typedef struct {
    int rgb_comp_colour;
    char filetype[2];
    int height;
    int width;
}
PPMHead;

/*PPMHead head[3];
{
    head[3].filetype;
    head[3].height;
    head[3].width;
}
PPMHead *ptr_head = NULL;
ptr_head = head;*/

PPMPixel * data; //Defines pointer to PPMPixel
int ** Array; //Double pointer defines as a pointer pointing to a pointer that is pointing to an integer
PPMPixel ** RGBArray; //Double pointer defines as a pointer pointing to a pointer that is pointing to the PPMPixel structure
FILE * fp;
int r, g, b;

void headercheck() {
    PPMHead * ptr_head, head;
    ptr_head = & head;

    fscanf(fp, "%s %d %d %d", head.filetype, & head.width, & head.height, & head.rgb_comp_colour);
    printf("%s %d %d %d", head.filetype, head.width, head.height, head.rgb_comp_colour);

    if (head.width > maxwidth || head.height > maxheight) {
        printf("\tInvalid image size. The maximum value of image is 1920x1080.\n");
        printf("\tImage size is %d x %d\n", head.width, head.height);
    } else {
        printf("\tImage size is valid\n");
        printf("\tImage size is %d x %d\n", head.width, head.height);
    }

    if ((strcmp(head.filetype, pgmtype) != 0) && (strcmp(head.filetype, ppmtype) != 0)) {
        printf("\tInvalid filetype\n");
    } else {
        if (strcmp(head.filetype, pgmtype) == 0) {
            printf("\t File is PGM type image\n");
        } else {
            if (strcmp(head.filetype, ppmtype) == 0) {
                printf("\t File is PPM type image\n");
            }
        }
    }

    if ((head.rgb_comp_colour == RGB_COMPONENT_COLOUR)) {
        printf("\t Image is 8 bit\n");
    } else {
        if (head.rgb_comp_colour > RGB_COMPONENT_COLOUR) {
            printf("Maximum bit-depth is 8 bits\n");
        } else {
            printf("\tImage is not 8 bit\n");
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    PPMHead * ptr_head, head;
    ptr_head = & head;

    char fname[100];
    printf("Enter file name: ");
    scanf("%s", fname);
    fseek(stdin, 0, SEEK_END);
    fp = fopen(fname, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("\tError while opening the file\n");
    } else {
        printf("\tReading in %s\n", fname);
    }

    //Checking for comments
    //Skip whitespace and comments

    headercheck();

    if (strcmp(head.filetype, pgmtype) == 0) {
        printf("\tReading in PGM image...\n");
        * Array = malloc(head.width * sizeof(int * )); //Points to malloc
        for (int i = 0; i < head.width; i++) {
            Array[i] = (int * ) malloc(head.height * sizeof(int));
            if ((Array = NULL)) {
                printf("Error allocating memory to the array");
            } else {
                printf("Memory allocated to the PGM array sucessfully");
            }
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < head.height; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < head.width; i++) {
                fscanf(fp, "%3d ", & Array[i][j]); //Scans the address of Array[i][j]
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);

    //Save PPM Array Into New PPM File
    FILE * pf;
    int i, j;
    char fname2[100];
    printf("Enter file name: ");
    scanf("%s", fname2);
    fseek(stdin, 0, SEEK_END);
    pf = fopen(fname2, "w");
    if (pf == NULL) {
        printf("\tError while opening the file\n");
    } else {
        printf("\tWriting in %s\n", fname2);
    }

    if (strcmp(head.filetype, pgmtype) == 0) {
        for (j = 0; j < head.height; j++) {
            fprintf(pf, "\n");
            for (i = 0; i < head.width; i++) {
                fprintf(pf, "%3d ", Array[i][j]);
                //fprintf(pf, "%3d ", **(Array+j*head[0].width + i));
            }
        }
    }

    fclose(pf);
    for (int i = 0; i < head.width; i++) {
        free(Array[i]);
        Array[i] = NULL;
    }
    free(Array);
    Array = NULL;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I see a problem here `char filetype[2];` A string with 2 characters also needs a third position to store the nul terminator. In the common idiom `malloc(strlen(s) + 1)`, the `+ 1` is there for this reason.

Comment: Oh yes ofc. It needs to be char filetype[3].

Comment: `fseek(stdin. 0, SEEK_END)` is dubious.  It should work if the standard input is redirected from a file, but it usually won't help if it comes from a pipe or terminal.

Comment: Note that although you print an error message after opening the file, your code then continues as if nothing was wrong.  You need to fix that.  You should report errors to `stderr`, not `stdout`, too.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'm using fseek so the enter key does not count as a character.

Comment: And I'm telling you it isn't guaranteed to work.

Comment: the posted code fails to compile!   Please correct and re-post

Comment: @DanielBland,   `fseek(stdin, 0, SEEK_END);` is looking for a EOF condition, so a `\n` does count